# Rails 4, Ruby 2.1 apparent memory leak on sign_in/sign_out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, memory-leaks, devise

I've got a pretty vanilla Rails 4, Ruby 2 app on Heroku. I've noticed R14 errors after awhile and I tracked down one source of increasing memory to sign_in/sign_out. So if I sign in a user then sign out I see memory go up by 1mb sometimes 10 mb. If I keep signing and signout the same user, memory goes up and up.

Some more details:

- Devise 3.2.4, Papertrail, Rollbar
- Dalli store / Memcachier
- Sessions last 90 minutes
- Nothing is put into session
- After sign in user is redirected to welcome page that is mostly fragment cached
- NewRelic doesn't give much info other than increasing memory usage
- Heroku log-runtime-metrics have been enabled
- Running only 1 Unicorn worker (since they run out of memory, would like to run 2 or 3)
- db connection pool of 2 with connection reaping every 10 seconds as recommended by Heroku

I've used this to identify that Strings and Arrays are increasing 1,000 String, 500 arrays every time a sign_in/sign_out occurs:

```
ObjectSpace.each_object.with_object(Hash.new(0)){|obj, h| h[obj.class] +=1 }.select{|k,v| puts "#{k} = #{v}"}
```

I guess my main question that if I'm using Dalli store/Memcachier for sessions then should there be any effect on Dyno memory when a user signs in? My assumption would be no. Any ideas on hunting this down?

Answer (score 0):

Are you on ruby 2.1.1 or 2.1.2? I had memory issues on ruby 2.1.1 and upgrading to 2.1.2 helped. You can read more here:
http://samsaffron.com/archive/2014/04/08/ruby-2-1-garbage-collection-ready-for-production